# How to count element in each list in the data frame with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Given such a data frame `df`:

```
0     1
1     [12]
1     [13]
2     [11,12]
1     [10,0,1]
....
```

I'd like to count a certain value, for instance, `'12'` in each list of `df`. So i tried:

```
df.apply(list.count('12'))
```

but got error: `TypeError: descriptor 'count' requires a 'list' object but received a 'str'`. But they are exactly `lists` in `df[1]`! How can I correct it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try first select column as Series by [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) and then [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function `x.count(12)`:

```
import pandas as pd

d = { 0:pd.Series([1,1,2,1]),
      1:pd.Series([[12], [13], [11,12 ],[10,0,1]])}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)  

print df 
   0           1
0  1        [12]
1  1        [13]
2  2    [11, 12]
3  1  [10, 0, 1]

print df.ix[:, 1]
0          [12]
1          [13]
2      [11, 12]
3    [10, 0, 1]
Name: 1, dtype: object

print df.ix[:, 1].apply(lambda x: x.count(12))   
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    0
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Or use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for selecting:

```
print df.iloc[:, 1].apply(lambda x: x.count(12))   
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    0
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

EDIT:

I think column `1` contains `NaN`.

You can use:

```
print df 
   0           1
0  1         NaN
1  1        [13]
2  2    [11, 12]
3  1  [10, 0, 1]

print df.ix[:, 1].notnull()
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
Name: 1, dtype: bool

print df.ix[df.ix[:, 1].notnull(), 1].apply(lambda x: x.count(12))   
1    0
2    1
3    0
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

EDIT2:

If you want filter by index (e.g. `0:2`) and by NaN in column `1`:

```
print df 
   0           1
0  1         NaN
1  1        [13]
2  2    [11, 12]
3  1  [10, 0, 1]

#filter df by index - only 0 to 2 
print df.ix[0:2, 1]
0         NaN
1        [13]
2    [11, 12]
Name: 1, dtype: object

#boolean series, where is not nul filtered df
print df.ix[0:2, 1].notnull()
0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: 1, dtype: bool

#get column 1: first is filtered to 0:2 index and then if is not null
print df.ix[0:2, 1][df.ix[0:2, 1].notnull()]
1        [13]
2    [11, 12]
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

```
#same as above, but more nice
df1 =  df.ix[0:2, 1]
print df1
0         NaN
1        [13]
2    [11, 12]
Name: 1, dtype: object

print df1[df1.notnull()]
1        [13]
2    [11, 12]
Name: 1, dtype: object

#apply count
print df1[df1.notnull()].apply(lambda x: x.count(12))   
1    0
2    1
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hello, why are you using `iloc` or `ix` when a simple name indexing `df[1]` does the job ?

Comment: I think it is best practices, but I cant find nice source.

Comment: I see what you mean: to avoid the ambiguity between label access and positional access. A quote from the pandas documentation [Indexing and Selecting Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) > Integers are valid labels, but they refer to the label and not the position.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think better is use `ix` or `iloc` for integer columns names.

Comment: I tried you answer too but got this error:`AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'count'`

Comment: Thanks, it works. But i don't understand how it works. How can I specify the rows to count, e.g, from `0` to `2`?  Seems `df.ix[df.ix[0:2, 1].notnull(), 1].apply(lambda x: x.count('12'))` doesn't work

Comment: It works, because it use [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and how you can specify rows - please give me a minute.

Comment: But when I tried `df.ix[df.ix[0:2, 1].notnull(), 1].apply(lambda x: x.count('12'))`, it returned `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided`

Comment: I wonder besides the boolean indexing, is there any `if-else` way enable me to set the value is zero if that row is `NaN` value

Answer (score 1):

The `count` has to be applied on the column.

```
# Test data
df = pd.DataFrame({1: [[1], [12], [13], [11,12], [10,0,1]]})

df[1].apply(lambda x: x.count(12))

0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    0
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

A modification to handle the case when some values are not stored in a list

```
# An example with values not stored in list 
df = pd.DataFrame({1: [12, [12], [13], [11,12], [10,0,1], 1]})

_check = 12
df[1].apply(lambda l: l.count(_check) if (type(l) is list) else int(l == _check))

0    1
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    0
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Why did I got this error: `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'count'`?

Comment: @ZICHAO LI Probably because all the elements in the column are not in a list but it is not what you've said in the question.

Comment: @ZICHAOLI Just modified my answer to handle the case where some values are not stored in a list. Tell me.

Comment: Indeed they are all in a list. But your solution is still very helpful. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional generator expression:

```
df = df = pd.DataFrame({0: [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2], 1: [np.nan, [13], [11, 12], [10, 0, 1], [12], [np.nan, 12]]})

target = 12
>>> sum(sub_list.count(target) 
        for sub_list in df.iloc[:, 1] 
        if not np.isnan(sub_list).all())
3
```

This is like the following conditional list comprehension:

```
>>> [sub_list.count(12) for sub_list in df.iloc[:, 1] if not np.isnan(sub_list).all()]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

The difference is that the former lazily evaluates each item in the list instead of first generating the entire list, so it is generally more efficient.